# How to use if inside RichText

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to display the old and the new price inside of a RichText.

```
if(regularPrice >= discountPrice){
    TextSpan(
            text: ' $regularPrice',
            style: TextStyle(
                decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                decorationThickness: 2.85,
            fontSize: 15,
            ontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
    TextSpan(
            text: ' $discountPrice',
            style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            ontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
}else{
    TextSpan(
            text: ' $regularPrice',
            style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            ontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
}
```

Can i use this logic inside a RichText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator):

```dart
class RichTextDiscountedPrice extends StatelessWidget {
  static const regularPrice = 100;
  static const discountedPriced = 95;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final regularPriceTextSpan = TextSpan(text: ' $discountedPriced', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));

    final discountedTextSpanList = [
      TextSpan(text: '$regularPrice', style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)),
      regularPriceTextSpan
    ];

    return Center(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: "Price ",
          style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
          children: <TextSpan>[
            if (regularPrice > discountedPriced) ...discountedTextSpanList else ...<TextSpan>[regularPriceTextSpan],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: discounted price]

[image: regular price]

Note: I edited the styles a little to reduce the number of lines for the example.